# the mu vector in gaussian process has the same value for every entry?

Tags: gaussian-process

I am trying to follow https://www.jgoertler.com/visual-exploration-gaussian-processes/

after several hours I arrived to:

[image]

This is N dimension... My question is, why is assumed that all $\mu$ have the same value? I understand the 'centering', what I don't understand is why we assume the entire N vector will have the same $\mu$. I was expecting to see N different '$\mu$'s

Answer (score 1):

Why? Quite simply, because we *can*, as per the centering/reparameterization thing you're quoting, and it simplifies the calculations.

We have one less variable to worry about, we can just pretend everything has mean zero and worry about getting the covariance matrices right instead.

If you know how you centered the data, you know how to recover the mean back from the model outputs without any loss of information in between, so... why not?

Comment: I see, but if I want to make my function jump from 0 to a 10,000. With the same mu, I would need to increase a loot the variance, that also means that  it can go to either 10,000 or -10,000 or anywhere inbetween... I guess my question is how can I make sure a function kinda goes from 0 to 100000 by only controlling the variance of it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. If you expect your function to range from 0 to 10,000, then your mean and variance are effectively both 5000, and you can recover it from the standard normal by doing $5000*\mu_{out}+5000$; similarly for 1 mil, your parameters are just 500,000 instead.

Comment: My explanation was bad, I mean making a function go from f(x) 0 to f(x) 10,000

Comment: ...do you mean that you want your function to only output positive numbers, by any chance? If so, that's another trick - log-scale your input data and exponentiate the model outputs.